# Command to get to bottom of tree

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a Linux command that will return the file path of the bottom most dir.

I've tried the following commands:
`find /home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/ -type d`

and

`tree -dfi /home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/`

Both these commands return:

```
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/generic
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/admin
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/logandnetworkactivity
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/qvm
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/qvm/a
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/reports
```

As you can see in the case of:

```
/home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/qvm

    /home/Alison/workspace/DirLevel1/DirLevel2/DirLevel3/DirLevel4/DirLevel5/DirLevel6/DirLevel7/qvm/a
```

It is returning `/qvm/` as well as `/qvm/a` where I just want the bottom dir.

Comment: What if there are multiple paths at the same depth? Do you need both or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
find . -type d | \
  awk -F/ '
    NF <= old_NF {print prev}
    {old_NF=NF; prev=$0}
    END {print $0}
  '
```

**Example:**

```
find . -type d
.
./backup
./source
./source/siteA
./source/siteA/regionA
./source/siteA/regionA/files
./source/siteA/regionB
./source/siteA/regionB/files
./source/siteA/regionD
./source/siteA/regionD/files
./source/siteA/regionC
./source/siteA/regionC/files
./source/dir with space
./source/siteB
./source/siteB/regionA
./source/siteB/regionA/files
./source/siteB/regionB
./source/siteB/regionB/files
```

Now the command from above gives:

```
./backup
./source/siteA/regionA/files
./source/siteA/regionB/files
./source/siteA/regionD/files
./source/siteA/regionC/files
./source/dir with space
./source/siteB/regionA/files
./source/siteB/regionB/files
```

**Short explanation:**

The plain `find . -type d` output is already sorted according to the directory structure. What you now want is **those lines (=paths) that are immediatly before a line that has the same or less depth. And the last line (always).**

This is what the `awk` command does. It splits input lines on the path separator (`-F/`), stores the number of fields and the line (`{old_NF=NF; prev=$0}`) and then compares the old number of fields to the current one and prints the stored line if number of fields is less than or equal (`NF <= old_NF {print prev}`). And it prints the last line always (`END {print $0}`).

Comment: The level won't always be the same so would need to be more flexible to get to the bottom level no matter how deep the path goes.

Comment: @Colin747 please see my updated answer...

Comment: But i t wont work appropriately on such a case (or am I misunderstanding the question?):
./source
./source/siteA
./source/siteA/regionA
./a/very/long/path/to/some/where/else
./a
this would only print the 4th line.

Comment: @SahandMozaffari before `find` prints ./a/very/long/path/to/some/where/else it definitely prints ./a, ./a/very, ... that's why it works ;-)